# Why does RavenDB perform an OR operation instead of an AND?

Tags: ravendb

Why is there a OR instead of an AND between the SEARCH and the WHERE?

The problem is that the current Lucene query is:

"OrganizationType:Boo ( Name:(Foo) ShortName:(Foo))"

instead of:

"OrganizationType:Boo **AND** ( Name:(Foo) ShortName:(Foo))"

How can I change that?

```
RavenQueryStatistics stats;
var organizationQuery = session.Query<Organization>()
                               .Statistics(out stats)
                               .Skip((request.Page - 1) * request.PageSize)
                               .Take(request.PageSize);

if (request.OrganizationType != default(OrganizationType))
{
    organizationQuery = organizationQuery.Where(o => o.OrganizationType == request.OrganizationType);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Query))
{
    organizationQuery = organizationQuery
                                         .Search(c => c.Name, request.Query, escapeQueryOptions: EscapeQueryOptions.AllowPostfixWildcard)
                                         .Search(c => c.ShortName, request.Query, escapeQueryOptions: EscapeQueryOptions.AllowPostfixWildcard);
}
```

I have added a screenshot with the proposed solution:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get only documents matching **all** sub-queries you to have to use `Intersect`. See the article [How to use intersect](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/session/querying/how-to-use-intersect) in the RavenDB documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Because Search is using OR by default. There is an optional parameter that set it to use AND.

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear enough. My problem is not the OR between the search but that the lucene query is "OrganizationType:Club ( Name:(F*) ShortName:(F*))" instead of "OrganizationType:Club AND ( Name:(F*) ShortName:(F*))". How can I achieve that?

Comment: Use the overload for the Search that tell it to use an AND

Comment: I tried out with the SearchOptions.And and the Lucene query is: "OrganizationType:Club ( AND Name:(liv*) ShortName:(liv*))" and I get an aggregate exception. I have added a screenshot below the question in order to illustrate it.